# CQS with dispatcher casting issues

Tags: c#

I am trying to build a microservice that pulls commands and queries off of a queue. My service watches a specific queue and pulls a message off that could be any type command for that domain. That message is pulled off and passed to the dispatcher. My problem is that in trying to make everything as generic as possible, my message is being passed into the dispatcher as an object, but the dispatcher needs a concrete IQuery class. I can cast it to IQuery because I know that it is that type, but when I try to resolve the dependencies in the dispatcher based on the type, it fails because the concrete type is not known. I will try to keep the code samples small and to the point:

**Main Service**

```
    private static async Task HandleMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEventArgs args) {
        await queryDispatcher.Dispatch((IQuery)args.Message.Payload);
    }
```

**Query Dispatcher**

```
public class QueryDispatcher : IQueryDispatcher {
    #region attributes
    private readonly IComponentContext _context;
    #endregion

    #region ctor
    public QueryDispatcher(IComponentContext context) {
        _context = context;
    }
    #endregion

    #region methods
    public async Task<IEvent> Dispatch<T>(T query) where T : IQuery{
        if (query == null) {
            return new ArgumentNullEvent(nameof(query));
        }

        var validator = _context.Resolve<IValidator<T>>();
        var handler = _context.Resolve<IQueryHandler<T>>();

        List<ValidationResult> errors = await validator.Validate(query);

        if(errors.Count == 0) {
            return await handler.Handle(query);
        } else {
            return new ValidationFailedEvent(query.Id, errors);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**Queue Message**

```
public class QueueMessage {
    public Guid OperationId { get; set; }
    public object Payload { get; set; }
}
```

**Concrete IQuery Impl**

```
public class GetSite : BaseQuery, IQuery {
    public Guid SiteGuid { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build the type using MakeGenericType:

```
var validator = _context.Resolve(typeof(IValidator<>)
                        .MakeGenericType(new[] { query.GetType() }));
var handler = _context.Resolve(typeof(IQueryHandler<>)
                      .MakeGenericType(new[] { query.GetType() }));
```

Comment: the problem with that is that Autofac is returning an object with that call and not a class of the expected type